# Swift - JSON function not updating correctly

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a JSON function that gets currency exchange data, but the function is only re-sending the JSON request every 28 times. Here is my code:

```
func fetchPrice() {
let url = URL(string: "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/EURUSD=x/quote?format=json")
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)

do {
    let object = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? NSDictionary

    if let dictionary = object as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let title = object?["list"] as! [String:Any]
        let title2 = title["resources"] as! [AnyObject]?
        let title3 = title2?[0] as! [String:Any]?
        let title4 = title3?["resource"] as! [String:Any]?
        let fields = title4?["fields"] as! [String:Any]?

        let price = fields?["price"] as! String

        print(fields?["price"] as! String)
        print(fields?["ts"] as! String)
        //print(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
        //print(dictionary)

    }
}
}

while true {
    fetchPrice()
    sleep(UInt32(1))
}
```

The URL does change the price every second, but it is not working when I try to refresh every second of few seconds. It works when I re-compile my playground just not in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer.  beginFetch code will perform your fetch every second until you call stopFetch:

```
    var fetchTimer: Timer!

    func beginFetch() {
        var fetchCount = 0
        fetchTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
            fetchCount += 1
            print("\n The timer has run \(fetchCount) times")
            self.fetchPrice()
        }
    }

    func stopFetch() {
        fetchTimer.invalidate()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this I am still having the same problem.

Comment: Clarify the problem:  is the fetch request not executing or is it not returning data? Those are two different issues.

Comment: It's executing, but it just repeats the same execution and returns wrong data.

Comment: it returns the same data, but both the US and Eurozone financial markets are closed so I don't expect a change in price until they are open.  Try again when they open.

Comment: No that is not correct. I have tried it for several hours. It executes if I recompile my playground, this is how I know that the problem is with the function. Also, the timestamp that is printed stays the same as the first timestamp (The time of the request).

Comment: The time stamp you are printing is from the API.  it is not the time of your request.  Its the time the API server updated the value.  The data you are printing is from the API.  If there is a problem with it, its with the yahoo server.  You posted this question several hours after the NY market close.  Are you sure the markets were open when you tried it?  try it again tomorrow.

Comment: Yes I am sure. Try running the code I posted in a playground. You will notice that it changes each time you run the project, but if you try to do it automatically it only changes every 30 seconds or so.